# Pandas name dataframe from a string in csv name

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have several csv with a string in their name (e.g city name) and want to read them in dataframe with the names derived from that city name.

example of csv names: data_paris.csv , data_berlin.csv

How can I read them in a loop to get df_paris and df_berlin?

What I tried so far:

```
all_files = glob.glob(./*.csv")

for filename in all_files:
    city_name=re.split("[_.]", filename)[1] #to extract city name from filename
    dfname= {'df' + str(city_name)}
    print(dfname)
    dfname= pd.read_csv(filename)
```

I expect to have df_rome and df_paris, but I get just dfname. Why?

A related question: [Name a dataframe based on csv file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751788/name-a-dataframe-based-on-csv-file-name)

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `df_paris` and `df_berlin`, you should create a dictionary `dfs` with keys `'paris'` and `'berlin'`, so you can do `dfs['paris']` and `dfs['berlin']`.

Comment: could you write as an answer and more detailed? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against automatic dynamic naming like `df_paris`, `df_berlin`. Instead, you should do:

```
all_files = glob.glob("./*.csv")

# dictionary of dataframes
dfs = dict()
for filename in all_files:
    city_name=re.split("[_.]", filename)[1] # to extract city name from filename

    dfs[city_name] =  pd.read_csv(filename) # assign to the dataframe dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your concepts.  If you want to reference dynamically data frames that have been loaded use a `dict`

```
all_files = glob.glob("./*.csv")

dfname={}
                      
for filename in all_files:
    city_name=re.split("[_.]", filename)[1] #to extract city name from filename
    dfname['df' + str(city_name)] = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(list(dfname.keys())
```

Comment: I can't see what you refer to....  how much coding have you done with `dict` and comprehensions?  you can always then reference a loaded df as `dfname["dfparis"]`.  The point of the `print()` was to show this.  Do you know a `dict` is a dynamic structure of key/value pairs?

Comment: yes I know dict! I just had not used/seen yet dataframe as dict.

Answer (score 0):

the only dataframe you're creating is "dfname." You just keep overwriting that each time you loop through. I guess you could do this using globals(), though honestly I'd probably just create a list or a dict of dataframes (as it seems others have suggested while I was typing this), or else create a named column for 'city' in a master dataframe that I just keep appending to. But, keeping with what you're specifically asking, you could probably do it like so:

```
all_files = glob.glob("./*.csv")

for filename in all_files:
    globals()[filename[5:-4]]=  pd.read_csv(filename)
```